# chrome extension opens javascript popup window then alerts in that window fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, window

```
function openindex()
{
OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin", "height=768, width=1024,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no, location=no");
OpenWindow.alert("hi");
}

openindex();
```

So this fails, a window is created blank or loads a webpage, there is no alert. Of course this works in a html document, but as a extension it fails and I do not know why.

Comment: btw im trying to do this all in javascript because this same script will be needed in firefox using greasemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but:

According to the original specs (Netscape) for window.open the **feature** string must **NOT** contain spaces.

PS if you set the url to "about:blank" first, then use (the following) does it work?

```
function openindex(){
  OpenWindow = window.open("about:blank", "newwin", "height=768,width=1024,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,location=no");
  OpenWindow.document.write('<script>alert("Hi");</script>');
  OpenWindow.document.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work. The window gets created fine, blank or otherwise (url). However I seem to not be able to communicate with that window once it is made, no document.write or alerts. I have only tested this in chrome and not in firefox yet

Comment: Any chance you can post more code or point to a sample test case for us to look at?